# How to know if a connection is being closed is abandaned or not?

Tags: tomcat, timeout, connection-pooling

I am using Tomcat Connection pooling and have set properties removeAbandoned=true and removeAbandonedTimeout=60 in roder to make sure any connection which takes more than 60 seconds should be abandoned.

Now , I want to notify the user if a connection is being closed because it is an abandaned connection.

Can anybody please help me in that.

Between, I know that i can set interceptors which will be invoked on every operation for on that connection but inside an interceptor how do i know whether the connection being closed is because it is abandoned connection.

Can anybody please help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

when the removeAbandoned is set to true the connections are removed from the connection pool. This is seamless to what the end user gets to see on the UI of the application as his request will be serviced by a different connection from the connection pool.

There is however, a property to log the abandoned connection using (if this is what you need)
    logAbandoned =true

This will log the abandanded connection in the log.

Additionally , Interceptors can be overridden for custom experiences.

Comment: One thing logAbandoned is not something for which i am looking at because right now I am not interesting in knowing the cause of the same. Also, you said request will be serviced by a different connection, are you sure about this, because i have read the documentation but it does not say anything like this. It just says that connection will be closed once it exceeds the abandoned timeout.